# How can I delete a shared file from Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

I have a shared file with someone and I don't want her to reach it anymore. She shared the file with me. Can I delete it permanently without the possibility that she will reach it again?

Will she get a notice about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the file is shared *with* you, then you cannot remove the other person's access, as they are the owner. In Sharing Settings they will appear as "Is owner".

If you have shared the file *with someone else*, then in Sharing Settings you can click the X to remove a person from viewing the file any longer.

[Sharing settings overview](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494886?hl=en) describes more options in detail. You can prevent someone from resharing a document, for example.

**Important note:** You cannot prevent a person from retaining a local copy of a document if they have already downloaded a copy to their computer. They will no longer be able to access the live document, but can reopen a document they have saved.