# What's an efficient way to delete shared Google Drive files?

Tags: google-drive, file-sharing

*(A [similar question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/55274/how-can-i-delete-a-shared-file-from-google-drive) didn't help.)*

When I try to delete a shared file, I get a message saying that it is still accessible by collaborators.

So what I've been doing instead is unsharing first, and then deleting.

There's nothing private in the file I'm trying to get rid of — but I made a new version of the file, which I want people to have access to and use; and I want to wipe out the obsolete version to prevent people from using it.  I want them to use the new one.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: It seems to me that you've stumbled on the best way: unshare then delete.

Comment: @AlE. - Thanks -- but it's so tedious when there are 20 collaborators....

Comment: See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59207140/1266040

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Deleting it simply moves it to the trash where collaborators may still access the file. If, however, you click the "trash" link and "delete forever" on the item in question, it is no longer accessible by collaborators.

Comment: +1 makes you wonder, what's wrong with saying in plain terms "File moved to Trash folder" (sigh)

Comment: but why delete and re-share when you could simply upload a new version to the very same file? (see my answer)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case for me. That is, if I "Remove" a file that I have already shared with another account, the file does not end up in the Trash. I first have to unshare the file, then I can delete (i.e., "Remove") it.

Comment: "Empty trash" will get rid of everything in one swell foop.  Click "Trash" and then the little down-pointing triangle.

Answer (score 6):

You should use the [Upload new version](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2409045?hl=en) feature rather than deleting/unsharing and sharing again. (You can delete earlier versions later.)

## Steps

1. On your computer, go to drive.google.com.
2. Right click on the file you want to replace.
3. Click Manage versions.
   [image: Manage versions screenshot]
4. Click Upload new version.
5. Select the new file on your computer.
6. After the upload finished, open the three dots menu of the old version
7. Click Delete to get rid of the old version.
   [image: old version menu screenshot]

Now everyone will see the new version instead of the old one.

Comment: Can you spell this out step by step, please, and explain how this will get rid of the file completely, and efficiently?  I haven't quite understood the procedure you're recommending.  Why would I need a new version, in general?  Also, if the folder itself is shared, any new version will also be shared, too, won't it?  Thanks.

Comment: sorry @aparente001 haven’t noticed your comment earlier.

>_Why would I need a new version, in general?_

I can only reply with your own words:
_I made a new version of the file, which I want people to have access to and use; and I want to wipe out the obsolete version to prevent people from using it. I want them to use the new one._

Comment: so @aparente001 the feature I linked to does exactly that: you can upload the new version, delete the old one, and the sharing / permissions remain the same.

Comment: @aparente001 I updated my answer with a step-by-step guide.

Comment: Thank you.  What if I don't have a new version of the file, but I just want to do some clean-up and get rid of files that aren't needed any more?

Comment: @aparente001 see the [other answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/90245/13892) for that.